# Facebook pages merge

Tags: facebook-pages

I decided to merge two pages. They have same name, both pages have same admins, belongs to same business account. But when I tried to merge pages it says that "The merge request is rejected". So what is the problem?

Comment: _The merge request is rejected_ is it full error message or you are getting anything else in error message?

Answer (score 1):

I believe your request got rejected because your both pages have same name. I would say, change the second page name first, but keep the page name similar to other page name with which you want to merge and then try to merge. Also, if you pages have physical address, then it should be same.

From [Facebook Help Centre](https://www.facebook.com/help/249601088403018/?ref=u2u):

> If you have 2 Facebook Pages for the same thing, you may be able to merge them if:
>
> - You're an [admin](https://www.facebook.com/help/289207354498410?helpref=faq_content) of both Pages.
> - Your Pages have similar names and represent the same thing.
> - Your Pages have the same [address](https://www.facebook.com/help/197254963682414?helpref=faq_content), if they have physical locations.
>
> Before you request a Page merge, please make sure that any campaigns you're running aren't pointing to the Page that will be deleted.

Before merging check that all these conditions are satisfied, otherwise your page merging request get rejected.

You may also check the [Pages-Specific Policies](https://www.facebook.com/policies/pages_groups_events/).

If still you face the issue, you can report a problem to [Facebook technical team](https://www.facebook.com/help/186570224871049/?ref=u2u).